# ThinkCentre M72e AMD Graphics Setup

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, hardware

The AMD Catalyst drivers for ThinkCentre M72e aren't working even though it's a Ubuntu Certified machine.  It installs the drivers but I get the hardware not supported error.  I removed the installed drivers and tried the one downloaded from AMD support website, but the installer says that the Graphics Adapter is not supported.

The card is an AMD HD7450.  I'm using Ubuntu LTS 12.04.3 with `xserver` version 1.13.3. Any kind of help is appreciated as I don't know what to do at this stage.

Comment: I know that AMD drivers are bad (and AMD should feel bad) on Ubuntu. Are you sure that your "Ubuntu Certification" includes AMD drivers ? I think they mean that the open-source driver is working.

Comment: Not sure what it means, I just noticed it on the Ubuntu website.  [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201302-12727/). There's no information as to what has been tested. It displays 2D graphics well at full resolution and can play video.  However, 3D is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the automatic tool provided, "Additional Drivers" on Ubuntu 12.04 (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/).

1. Install "Additional Drivers" (if it's already installed, nothing will change) :

   `sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk`
2. Run the application (Open it with Ubuntu launcher or in "System Settings") :

   `jockey-gtk`
3. Follow the instructions in the GUI.

Comment: I tried that already, but with both the normal and experimental driver.  For either one I get the "Unsupported Hardware" logo in the bottom right corner. 3D acceleration is not working.

Comment: I answered with another way to install drivers. Check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Installing AMD/ATI Driver :**

1. Prerequisites :

   - repositories `main`, `universe` and `restricted` are active (check it in Software-Sources) :

     ```
     gksudo software-properties-gtk
     ```
   - your system is up-to-date :

     ```
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
     ```
   - you have a backup of xorg.conf if it exists :

     ```
     sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
     ```
   - If a propriatery driver was already used, remove it :

     ```
     sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
     ```
2. Install the AMD/ATI driver from the repositories :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
   ```
3. Reboot.

---

When you use AMD/ATI propriatery drivers, there is a big chance that "Unsupported Hardware" shows up in your screen. You can correct that :

1. Download the latest Catalyst driver from the "Linux" page in [AMD official website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) (use the correct architecture! [x86] for 32 bits or [x86_64] for 64 bits)
2. Make the *.run* file executable :

   ```
   chmod +x amd-catalyst-*.run
   ```
3. Extract the driver with the command :

   ```
   ./amd-catalyst*.run  --extract
   ```
4. Enter the extracted directory and go to the subfolder *common/etc/ati* :

   ```
   cd <NameOfExtractedDirectory>/common/etc/ati
   ```
5. Copy the file named *control* and paste it in */etc/ati* :

   ```
   sudo cp control /etc/ati/
   ```
6. Restart, and the "unsupported hardware" message is gone !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This card was giving me trouble in Windows too, frequent driver crashes, etc.  Went to a local computer shop and got an NVidia card for $40.  Works great in both environments now.